# How does one install a minimal gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, xfce

I've just installed xubuntu and removed everything I don't need. Now I'd like to install gnome -shell but not any of the other gnome packages. Ideally, I'll have *only* xfce related programs with the addition gnome-shell (and everything needed to have a fully functional gnome-shell panel / system tray).

What is the proper way to accomplish this? I'd like to keep the number of installed packages to a minimum.

Comment: You can use `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` to install only  gnome-shell and some additional packages needed for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often use this parameter of `apt` for such things:

```
   --no-install-recommends
       Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for installing.
       Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
```

Use it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install gnome-shell
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.