# Is there a way to install Ubuntu (specifically with Gnome) and not get all of the software that comes along with it?

Tags: gnome, software-installation

I just installed Ubuntu with Gnome and there is a lot of software (i.e. `Books` `Calendar` `Color Profile Viewer` that I do not want and have to manually uninstall.

Is there a way to install Gnome and Ubuntu without this software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one install a minimal gnome-shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462107/how-does-one-install-a-minimal-gnome-shell)

Comment: I do not think that it is duplicate, as OP is asking to install a fresh Gnome desktop system without additional software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**Ubuntu minimal CD installation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) we will be asked what we are going to install.

1. On booting the minimal ISO choose *Install*

   [image]
2. Answer several question regarding locale, user, keyboard etc.
3. Select from a list what to install

   [image]

We can choose a complete desktop environment from the list above but then all recommended packages for that DE will also be installed.

**Selected nothing** from above to reboot to a command line but with fully supported networking and package management. From there we can further fine-tune our individual installation (e.g. install just a [minimal GNOME shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462107/how-does-one-install-a-minimal-gnome-shell)).

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu `mini.iso` in BIOS mode

If you want to install your Ubuntu system in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), you can start from the very small  Ubuntu `mini.iso` file.

### Ubuntu Server amd64 iso file in UEFI mode and BIOS mode

If you want to install your Ubuntu system in UEFI mode, the `mini.iso` does not work. But you can start from the Ubuntu Server amd64 (64-bit) iso file. The result will be almost exactly the same (in BIOS mode) as from the `mini.iso` file, and it works in UEFI mode, so this is a good alternative :-)

### Install a minimal system or select from the Software Selection menu

You can install a minimal system with a text screen interface, boot into it and from there install only the program packages, that you want. This way you can install a simple window manager and a minimal amount of software, or as in your case, a minimal gnome shell as suggested in the answer by @Takkat.

You can also select some of the alternatives from the Software Selection menu in the installer.